# SQL Query....Update table with Multiple Criteria with each Single field value..Like...Do Until....Loop...Next

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a multipleValue field which contains Multiple Designations like... Doctor,Nurse, ANM, Clerk etc.

I want to update a table where Designation Match with each Designation. My Code is following but success with First Designation only. How to Update all designation using code like.... DO Until.... Loop....Next.... in sql query

```
Private Sub PostAssigned_AfterUpdate()

Dim strCriteria As String
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim strClear, strUpdate As String

For Each varItem In Me![PostAssigned].Value
  strCriteria = strCriteria & varItem & ","
Next


strClear = "UPDATE MasterGeneralData SET MasterGeneralData.DA_ID = 0 WHERE (((MasterGeneralData.DA_ID)= " & Me.DAAAID & "));"
DoCmd.RunSQL (strClear)

strUpdate = "UPDATE MasterGeneralData SET MasterGeneralData.DA_ID = " & Me.DAAAID & " WHERE (((MasterGeneralData.Emp_Design)= '" & Left$([strCriteria], InStr([strCriteria], ",") - 1) & "'));"
DoCmd.RunSQL (strUpdate)

MsgBox "Dealing Assistant details Updated successfully "

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Kindly provide the sample data and sample expected result.

Comment: I have a table named tabMain with DAID and Designation Field... Data Type of DAID is Number  and Designation is String. I also have a form frmUpdateDAID where two Fields.. First .... DAID is Number and Second PostAssigned is Multivalue Field which have many Designations... My question is that when I update PostAssigned field on Form after selecting multiple designation then should update DAID field of table with value of Form DAID field where Designation of table equal to each designation selected in form field named PostAssigned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes... I got it... Working Fine..
My code is.

```
Private Sub PostAssigned_AfterUpdate()

Dim strCriteria As String
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim strClear, strUpdate As String
Dim LArray() As String

For Each varItem In Me![PostAssigned].Value
  strCriteria = strCriteria & varItem & ","
Next

LArray = Split(strCriteria, ",")

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

strClear = "UPDATE MasterGeneralData SET MasterGeneralData.DA_ID = 0 WHERE (((MasterGeneralData.DA_ID)= " & Me.DAAAID & "));"
DoCmd.RunSQL (strClear)

For i = LBound(LArray) To UBound(LArray)
strUpdate = "UPDATE MasterGeneralData SET MasterGeneralData.DA_ID = " & Me.DAAAID & " WHERE (((MasterGeneralData.Emp_Design)= '" & LArray(i) & "'));"
DoCmd.RunSQL (strUpdate)
Next i

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

MsgBox "Dealing Assistant details Updated successfully "

End Sub
```